# PHP shell_exec() returns different result to running same line in command line

Tags: python, php, shell-exec

So, I have a python script that I've 'compiled' into a .exe using PyInstaller. The script is using [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) for the command line interface. It will return either '0' or '1' depending on the passed parameter. It works on both my development machine as well as the machine running the website when called via command line.

```
C:\wamp64\www\nested_folders\SChecker.exe --serial="051326584"
```

But when called in PHP on the website via , where the passed $_serial is passed from a form POST :

```
$cmd = "C:\\wamp64\\www\\nested_folders\\SChecker.exe --serial=$_serial";
$cmd_result = shell_exec($cmd);
```

It always returns '0'. Always. I've checked the passed $cmd value as it is passed to the shell_exec() and the passed value works fine via command line.

Any ideas or help are much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I've now figured out what was going on.

I first created an equivalent process as a .bat file, to check if it was coming from the python script. But it persisted, as it turned out there was an error occurring but it wasn't being flagged back at all. It was identified by adding `2>&1` to the end of the cmd line that called the bat. This reveled I was getting an 'Access is denied' error.

This was due to the website not being run as my user, so didn't have the permissions to run the file.